# Mobx component not re-rendering on change in observable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am creating a React application and using Mobx for state management. Here is my code:

Store:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

class UnlockApp {

    @observable unlockPoints = 9;
    @observable pattern = null;
    @observable patternInProgress = false;
    @observable lastPoint = null;
    @observable allNodes = null;
    @observable lastNode = null;
    @observable currentX = null;
    @observable currentY = null;
    @observable isPatternLineEmpty = true;

    @action onPointPress = (point) => {
        this.pattern = [];
        this.pattern.push(point);
        this.patternInProgress = true;
        this.lastPoint = point;
        this.isPatternLineEmpty = false;
    }

    @action drawLine = (currentX, currentY) => {
        if (this.patternInProgress) {
            this.lastNode = this.allNodes[this.lastPoint].current;
            this.currentX = currentX;
            this.currentY = currentY;
        }
    }

    @action handleMouseEnter = (point) => {
        if (this.patternInProgress) {
            this.pattern.push(point);
            this.lastPoint = point;
            this.isPatternLineEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    @action stopCounting = () => {
        this.patternInProgress = false;
        this.lastPoint = null;
    }

    @action updateNodes = (nodes) => {
        this.allNodes = nodes;
    }

}

export default new UnlockApp();
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';
import PatternLine from './components/pattern-line/pattern-line';
import PatternScreen from './components/pattern-screen/pattern-screen';
import UnlockApp from './store';

const App = observer(() => {
    console.log(UnlockApp.currentX);
    return (
        <div>
            <PatternScreen store={UnlockApp} />
            {
                UnlockApp.patternInProgress &&
                <PatternLine lastNode={UnlockApp.lastNode}
                    currentX={UnlockApp.currentX}
                    currentY={UnlockApp.currentY} />
            }
        </div>
    )
})
```

There are two issue:

1) If I remove `console.log(UnlockApp.currentX)` from `App` component, `App` no longer re-renders when `currentX` changes. Why is this happening? I am already using `currentX` as a prop value inside `App`, so should it not automatically re-render?

2) Whenever I press down the mouse and `onPointPress` gets called, it successfully updates `patternInProgress` to `true`. As `patternInProgress` is an `observable` and being used inside the render method of the component `App`, `App` re-renders when `patternInProgress` changes to `true` inside `onPointPress` method. This causes the re-render of `PatternLine` component also (which is desired).

However, the issue is that the props that are being passed to `PatternLine` are not being updated (`null` is passed instead). i.e. the `drawLine` method is not successfully updating `lastNode`, `currentX` and `currentY` inside the store.

I can't figure out why this is happening. What am I doing wrong here?
Please note that I have not shown the code of the component that calls `drwaLine` method. However, I have already tested that the calling component correctly passes `currentX` and `currentY` to `drwaLine`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a typo. You're importing *PatterLine* when it should say *PatternLine*.

Comment: Somehow the `n` got deleted while pasting the code here.It's mentioned correctly in my code. Corrected in question now.

Comment: When and how is stopCounting called?

Comment: `stopCounting` is called when the user releases the mouse. And `onPointPress` is called when user presses the mouse down without lifting it up. However, the app in its current state never reaches calling of `stopCounting` as it crashes as soon as `onPointPress` is called and it tries to render `PatternLine` (which fails because the `props` being passed to it are `null` as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Have you debugged the onPointPress then? I would simply console log the (point) and see what data you have there. Maybe move up the flag "patternInProgress" and see if it still breaks. I have very limited Mobx experience so I cannot test it from my environment.

Comment: I figured out the issue. Basically, `patternInProgress` and other observables `lastNode`, `currentX` and `currentY` are getting updated in different methods. So as soon as `patternInProgress` gets updated, `PatternLine` component re-renders. But at this time, other mentioned observables have not yet been updated, so their value is still `null`. I can check for `null` values before invoking `PatternLine` just like I checked for `patternInProgress` by doing `UnlockApp.patternInProgress && < PatternLine/>`.

Comment: However, I am still trying to figure out if there is a better way to render components conditionally when they depend on more than one observables?